# How to get elements from links in Revit using macros with C#?

Tags: c#, macros, revit

How can I get the elements from a certain category from a list of linked models into my project with a macro in C# language?. I apply a FilteredElementCollector and get the links, but then I'm unable to get the GetLinkedDocument to iterate over them and obtain the elements I'm trying to get. 
Hope that my question is clear.

```
//Get Document:
Document doc = this.Document;

//Get links:
FilteredElementCollector links = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_RvtLinks);

//Get elements:
string names = "";
foreach (Element e in links) 
{
    FilteredElementCollector coll = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_PlumbingFixtures);
    names += coll + "\n" + "\n";
}

//Mostrar resultado:

TaskDialog.Show("Document", "Document Name " + "\n" + "\n" + names);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a discussion of [accessing lined element](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/09/access-to-individual-elements-in-linked-projects.html) with several pointers to further related discussions.